# routing an mvc4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having some troubles trying to get a route to work so far I have

```
    routes.MapRoute("Stores","{s}",new { controller = "Stores", action = "Index", s = UrlParameter.Optional});

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: null,
            namespaces: new[] { "NS.Web.Controllers" }
        );
```

I am trying to browse to the controller via /stores/store-abc however I get a 404.

What am I doing wrong with my routes?

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong with my routes?

Your route definition doesn't match the url pattern that you are using:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Stores", 
    "stores/{s}", 
    new { 
        controller = "Stores", 
        action = "Index", 
        s = UrlParameter.Optional 
    }
);
```

And your `Stores` controller:

```
public class StoresController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string s)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```